# gulp-typescript and typescript's new @types typings?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, gulp-typescript, typescript2.0

I have installed `@types/jasmine` as a devDependency.

My gulp task to compile my typescript is like so:

```
gulp.task('compile:tests', ['compile:typescript', 'clean:tests'], function () {
    var project = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', { typescript: typescript });

    var tsResult = gulp.src(['spec/**/*spec.ts'])
        .pipe(ts(project));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest('spec/'));
});
```

and my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

but this results in the errors:

> spec\linter.spec.ts(7,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
>   spec\linter.spec.ts(8,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
>   spec\linter.spec.ts(17,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
>   spec\linter.spec.ts(20,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.

How can I get typescript (when used by gulp-typescript) to recognize the `@types/...` typings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:** 
latest version fixes the issue: install with

`npm install gulp-typescript@3`

**pre gulp-typescript@3:** 
So far my work around has been to manually include all @types typings, like so:

```
gulp.src(['spec/**/*spec.ts', "./node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"])
```

if you have conflicting versions of typings (here's looking at you `@types/node@x`) then you can skip over them to avoid the duplicates:

```
gulp.src([
  paths.source + '**/*.ts', 
  "node_modules/@types/**/index.d.ts", 
  "!node_modules/@types/**/node_modules/**/index.d.ts"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `project.src()` instead of `gulp.src(['typings-glob', 'sources-glob'])`.

** For some reason, in project I'm working on, transpilation takes ~3 seconds more when `project.src()` used, so I stick with the `gulp.src` option.

Comment: Just tested this; doesn't work for me if I exclude node_modules. (without the exclusion it blows up with other errors) :(

Comment: you can use _include_ property instead of or with _exclude_. See [tsconfig schema](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig)

Answer (score 0):

<s>The following work for me.</s>

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "files": [
        "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

nvm, that wont work, neither does using "include" and "exclude" together.